# When launching Codename One's Gui Builder, on Eclipse, I get the error "Unhandled event loop exception"

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, codenameone, builder

As per tutorials I set up the GUI Builder with the file wizard. Then when I ctrl-click the form created and try to open it with the GUI Builder nothing happens
other than the error message `"Unhandled event loop exception"; Plug-in= "org.eclipse.ui"` with the Date and time given:`12/04/2020, 20:39`.

I am using

```
mac: Version 10.15.1 
Eclipse: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
```

I also can't open Codename One Settings on project... I can open the ResourceEditorApp, via Theme.res file.my current version is 1.1 Build #: 20171229

With regard to the error and greg-449 request:

The "Exception Stack Trace" field:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at                codenameoneplugin.GUIBuilderLauncher.open(GUIBuilderLauncher.java:40)
at       org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$31.run(WorkbenchPage.java:5397)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openExternalEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:5388)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3253)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:323)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.lambda$0(OpenWithMenu.java:180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1502)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1525)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1510)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1314)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4082)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3699)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessor   Impl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

While the "Session Data" Reads:

```
    eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
    java.version=1.8.0_131
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IE
    Framework arguments:  -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product   -    keyring     /Users/"name"/.eclipse_keyring
     Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -    product     org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring      /Users/"name"/.eclipse_keyring

    This is a continuation of log file /Users/"name"/eclipse-          workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
   Created Time: 2020-04-12 20:31:14.758
```

As requested by Shai. I ran this command in terminal `":/usr/libexec/java_home -V"` which produced these results:

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (4): Matching Java Virtual Machines
>   (4): 1.8.0_131, x86_64:   "Java SE 8"
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
>   1.8.0_25, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
>   1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home
>   1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home
>   –

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. (Note on macOS Finder does not normally show files/folder starting with .)

Comment: What's the JDK with which Eclipse is running?
Notice this isn't the JDK for the project but the JDK that physically loaded eclipse in eclipse.ini. Notice we only support JDK 8 from Oracle or ZuluFX. Or JDK 11 from anyone. We don't support newer JDKs at this time.

Comment: -vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib

Comment: To be honest I am not 100% if i have delivered what was requested... Let me know please.

Comment: I simply didn't have the time for this, now, but the problem I am guessing is an eclipse one.... ATM I am working away on the codename One GUI Builder via Netbeans. I would be happy to revisit this post June, deadline head til then.